# Autofill data until next value is reached (but miss out one row each time)

Tags: google-sheets, autofill

I have a student attendance [data sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHj5YBcrgh8pmf2Wpvqr-2fDtZr6likRYYZ8EferRYk/edit?usp=sharing) in which I need each student's name to appear in Column A, but only where the row for that student contains a subject. As you can see, I'm nearly there. In cell A4 I typed:

```
=B3
```

and in cell A5 I typed:

```
=IF(B4="",A4,B4)
```

...then just autofilled down from there. However, cells A17 and A31 (where a new student name appears on Column B) are messing up a formula I have on another sheet that references Column A on this sheet. Therefore, I'd like to leave these particular cells blank if possible, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: So you want to leave only those two cells blank? Why can't you just delete their contents then?

Comment: Sorry SpiderPig - I should have mentioned that I have approx. 120 students in the actual sheet. I just copied 3 over to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I duplicated the sheet in your shared spreadsheet and entered in cell A3 this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(C3:C),,if(row(C3:C) <= max(row(C3:C)),vlookup(row(C3:C),filter({row(C3:C),B3:B},len(B3:B)),2),)))
```

that seems to deliver the expected output. 
See if that works for you ?

Comment: Hi JPV. Thanks for your help. Not sure If I'm missing something, but in the copy you made, cells A17 and A31 still have content in them, but they should be blank???

Comment: Thanks JPV, works a treat! I have a unique function in another sheet that scans Column A on this sheet and pulls all the row data for each student. It looks like =UNIQUE(Gr6!A1:A). It is treating the blank rows in my original sheet as a unique value and so in my other sheet I always have one blank row of data somewhere in between the student data. Is there any way to tell a unique function to ignore blank rows? Thanks

Comment: =UNIQUE(FILTER(Gr6!A1:A , LEN(Gr6!A1:A)))

Answer (score 0):

I made another copy and entered this formula into A5: `=IF(B5="", IF(B4="",A4,B4), "")`